# Insert JSON data to database in Angularjs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json

Im working on a form which has a dynamic generated fields. My problem is I cant insert data from those generated fields. I tried this thread [How to insert json array into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523575/how-to-insert-json-array-into-mysql-database) but Its not working for me.

I tried to populate the data when transferred to PHP but got no luck.

**DB Connection**

```
<?php
class DbConfig 
{   
    private $_host = 'localhost';
    private $_username = 'root';
    private $_password = '';
    private $_database = 'machines';

    protected $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!isset($this->connection)) {

            $this->connection = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_username, $this->_password, $this->_database);

            if (!$this->connection) {
                echo 'Cannot connect to database server';
                exit;
            }           
        }   

        return $this->connection;
    }
}
?>
```

**JSON data**

```
    $scope.columns = [
{"id":1,"brand":"robotworx","tonnage":"200","tableSize":"20x50","pressType":"Kiss Cutting"},
{"id":2,"brand":"fanuc","tonnage":"100","tableSize":"30x60","pressType":"Swing Arm"}

];
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.register=function(){   
    $http.post("http://localhost/clickermag/controller/register.php", {
    'company':$scope.company,
    'email':$scope.email,
    'phone':$scope.phone,
    'position':$scope.position,
    'firstName':$scope.firstName,
    'lastName':$scope.lastName,
    'presses':$scope.columns
  })

    .then(function(response){
                    console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
                },function(error){
                    alert("Sorry! Data Couldn't be inserted!");
                    console.error(error);

                });
        }
```

**PHP file**

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

//including the database connection file
include_once("../classes/Crud.php");

$crud = new Crud();


$company = $data->company;
$email = $data->email;
$phone = $data->phone;
$position = $data->position;
$firstName = $data->firstName;
$lastName = $data->lastName;
$ownedPress = $data->presses;

        //insert data to database   
$result = $crud->execute("INSERT INTO users(company, email, phone, position, first_name, last_name) VALUES('$company','$email','$phone','$password','$position','$firstName','$lastName')");

$last_id = $crud->user_id;

foreach($data as $item) {
       $pressesQuery = $crud->execute("INSERT INTO owned_presses(user_id, brand, tonnage, table_size, press_type) VALUES ('$last_id','$item[brand]','$item[tonnage]','$item[tableSize]','$item[pressType]')");
     }

?>
```

I need to put the data from the generated fields to the second query.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Now,

```
foreach($data as $item) {
```

Why are you looping through `$data`, shouldn't you be looping through `$ownedPress`?

And, I'm not sure how `Crud.php` is implemented, but I'd assume it'd be:

```
$last_id = $result->user_id;
```