# How to insert entirely json object to table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, sql-insert

Suppose I have a table like the following:

```
 id| name | family
---+------+---------
 1 | iman | marashi
 2 | mike | ...
 3 | john | ...
 4 |      |
```

and I also have an Json object to **insert** to the table like the following:

```
{"name ":"will","family":"smith"}
```

How can I **insert together** an Json object to a table given that the fields of the table and the keys of the Json  object are the same?

Without having to parsing the Json object.

I don't want to use this method:

```
$name = $data["name"]; 
$family = $data["family"];
```

Comment: What backend are you using to store to db?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate question, [How to insert json array into mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523575/how-to-insert-json-array-into-mysql-database)

Comment: Do you use a version of MySQL that supports JSON functions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PDO, you can provide an associative array to fill in the parameters of a query.

```
$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO yourTable (name, family) VALUES (:name, :family)");
$data = json_decode($json_object, true);
$query->execute($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that Barmar provided the correct answer if you are running PDO.

For the sake a completeness, you could also do this purely with MySQL, using `json_extract()` to read directly from the json string given as parameter:

```
insert into mytable (name, family) values(
    json_unquote(json_extract(:js, '$.name')),
    json_unquote(json_extract(:js, '$.family'))
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4074dc2c0afd56cd4f2a97d417f9e67)**:

```
create table mytable (
    id int auto_increment primary key, 
    name varchar(50), 
    family varchar(50)
):

insert into mytable (name, family) values(
    json_unquote(json_extract('{"name":"will","family":"smith"}', '$.name')),
    json_unquote(json_extract('{"name":"will","family":"smith"}', '$.family'))
);

select * from mytable;
```

```
id | name | family
-: | :--- | :-----
 1 | will | smith
```

Comment: no need to provide an answer here i think this one also covered me, besides the `PDO` one. I think this way is better given the proper MySQL server version.